# Deep copy by names and ignore their types

Tags: java

We need to transfer our models into view objects, for example :

```
class Model {
   public UserModel user;
   public List<GroupModel> groups;
}

class VO {
   public UserVO user;
   public List<GroupVO> groups;
}
```

Let's see we have already load `Model` from database, and need to convert it into `VO`, is there any existing tool to make it ?

#### === UPDATE ===

`UserVO` and `UserModel` have the same data fields.

Comment: What are the relations between UserModel/UserVO and GroupModel/GroupVO?

Comment: @sp00m It seems there is one to one relation based on the variable name.  BeanUtils.copyProperties should help you in some way.

Comment: @sp00m, I've tried `BeanUtils` from apache-commons, but it doesn't work, it seems `BeanUtils` only works for the same types ?